# Fredholm Alternative as seen in PDEs, part 3

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

[...continued from part 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138648/fredholm-alternative-as-seen-in-pdes-part-2)

This is the **last** set of questions concerning the last part of Evans' proof in the Fredholm Alternative. As stated in my previous question, I do not have functional analysis background, but I want to still understand the proof. So my questions will be fundamental and basic. Any answers and clarifications are welcomed.

With that said, I am printing the theorem below, along with the second excerpt of the textbook's proof and my basic questions to follow.

(PDE Evans, Appendix D, Theorem 5)

> **THEOREM 5** (Fredholm Alternative)**.** *Let $K : H \to H$ be a compact linear operator. Then*
>
> (i) *$N(I-K)$ is finite dimensional,*
>
> (ii) *$R(I-K)$ is closed,*
>
> (iii) *$R(I-K)=N(I-K^*)^\perp$,*
>
> (iv) *$N(I-K)=\{0\}$ if and only if $R(I-k)=H$,*
>
> *and*
>
> (v) $\dim N(I-K)=\dim N(I-K^*)$.

The last excerpt of the textbook proof:

> 7. Next we assert $$\dim N(I-K) \ge \dim R(I-K)^\perp.$$ To prove this, suppose instead $\dim N(I-K) < \dim R(I-K)^\perp$. Then there exists a bounded linear mapping $A : N(I-K) \to R(I-K)^\perp$ which is one-to-one, but *not* onto. Extend $A$ to a linear mapping $A : H \to R(I-K)^\perp$ by setting $Au=0$ for $u \in N(I-K)^\perp$. Now $A$ has a finite-dimensional range and so $A$ and thus $K+A$ are compact. Furthermore $N(I-(K+A)) = \{0\}$. Indeed, if $Ku+Au=u$, then $u-Ku=Au \in R(I-K)^\perp$. Hence $u-Ku = Au = 0$. Thus $u \in N(I-K)$ and so in fact $u=0$, since $A$ is one-to-one on $N(I-K)$. Now apply assertion (iv) to $\tilde{K}=K+A$. We conclude $R(I-(K+A))=H$. But this is impossible: if $v \in R(I-K)^\perp$, but $v \not\in R(A)$, the equation $$u-(Ku+Au)=v$$ has no solution.

a. I understand the bounded lienar mapping $A : N(I-K) \to R(I-K)^\perp$ is not onto because $\dim N(I-K) \not= \dim R(I-k)^\perp$. But why is $A$ considered one-to-one?

b. Under what circumstances can we extend $A$ to a linear mapping $A : H \to R(I-K)^\perp$? In particular, I don't see how this justifies $A$ has finite-dimensional range, which would make $A$ compact.

c. Given that $K+A$ is compact, how can we show that $R(I-(K+A))=H$, so that we can use assertion (iv) to conclude that $N(I-(K+A))=\{0\}$?

d. When we establish that $u-Ku=Au=0$, why does this mean $u \in N(I-K)$? I thought earlier the proof mentioned that $u \in N(I-K)^\perp$. Is this because if $u \in N(I-K)$, then $Au=0$, and also if $u \in N(I-K)^\perp$ then $Au=0$ just the same?

e. Since $A$ is one-to-one on $N(I-K)$, does $Au=0$ imply $u=0$, and so $N(I-K)=\{0\}$?

> 8. Since $R(I-K^*)^\perp = N(I-K)$, we deduce from step 7 that 
>      \begin{align}
>    \dim N(I-K^*) &\ge \dim R(I-K^*)^\perp \\ &= \dim N(I-K).
>    \end{align}
>      The opposite inequality omes from interchanging the roles of $K$ and $K^*$. This establishes (v). $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \Box$
>
> **Remark.** Theorem 5 asserts in particular either
>   \begin{cases} \text{for each }f \in H \text{, the equation }u-Ku=f \\ \text{has a unique solution}\tag{$\alpha$} \end{cases} or else \begin{cases} \text{the homogeneous equation }u-Ku=0 \\ \text{has solutions } u\not=0.\tag{$\beta$} \end{cases} This dichotomy is the *Fredholm alternative*.

f. The proof in step 7 shows that $u - Ku = 0$ when $u=0$, though this is only when we assume the contrary ("suppose instead $\dim N(I-K) < \dim R(I-K)^\perp$"). Do we take the opposite of the previous statement, that is the opposite of $u=0$ is $u \not= 0$, and we arrive at $(\beta)$?

g. How do we get $u-Ku=f$ in $(\alpha)$? Step 7 also has $u - (Ku+Au)=v$ which implies no solution. But again the proof assumes the contrary. So to arrive at $(\alpha)$, we can say the opposite and say that $u - (Ku+Au)=v$ does indeed have a unique solution. Can we say this? And say that $u-Ku=v+Au=f$, where $f := v+Au$?

Comment: Notations: $I$ is the identity operator, $N$ the "null space" or more commonly the kernel, and $R$ the range or image. and $H$ is a  Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.) By absurd one assumes the contrary of what we want to proove i.e. that  $\mathrm{dim}\ N(I-K) < \mathrm{dim}\ R(I-K)^{\perp}$. It is from this assumption that one gets the *existence* of $A$ injective but not surjective: let $\mathcal{B}_1$ be a basis of $N(I-K)$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ a basis of $R(I-K)^{\perp}$, one can now *choose* to define $A$ as an operator mapping each basis vectors of $\mathcal{B}_1$ to a different basis vectors of $\mathcal{B}_2$ (contains more vectors by assumption) so that $A$ is injective.

b.) This is always possible: complete the basis $\mathcal{B}_1$ (of $N(I-K)$) into a basis $\mathcal{B}_H$ of the whole space $H$. A linear map is completely determined by the images of the basis vectors, so it suffices to assign a value to the additional vectors of $\mathcal{B}_H$ (which were not in $\mathcal{B}_1$).

Notations: $\mathcal{B}_1= (\mathbf{e}_1,\cdots , \mathbf{e}_n),\ \mathcal{B}_2= (\mathbf{f}_1,\cdots , \mathbf{f}_p)\ $ (with $n<p$ by absurd assumption). One could choose $A$ as follows
 $$A\cdot \mathbf{e}_i := \mathbf{f}_i,\quad \forall\ 1\leq i\leq n$$
(then extended by 0 on a supplementary of of $N(I-K)$.) Such a map has image the span of $(\mathbf{f}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{f}_n)$ which is finite dimensional.

c.) and d.) the argument you copied is meant to show $N(I-(K+A))=\{0\}$ directly and then obtain $R(I-(K+A))= H$ by (iv). It goes as follows: take an element $u$ in $N(I-(K+A))=\{0\}$ then

$$(I-(K+A)) (u)=0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad u -K u = A u$$
Left hand side of the last equality is in $R(I-K)$ by definition and r.h.s. in $R(I-K)^{\perp}$ by construction of $A$: both terms must be $0$. But vanishing of l.h.s. means that $u\in N(I-k)$ and $A$ is injective on that subspace, so that now, vanishing of r.h.s. implies that $u$ itself is $0$.

The different parts of the proof are independent, if $u$ was mentionned earlier it's probably not the same here.

e.) The business with the completion of some basis can be reformulated as the decomposition $H = N(I-K) + V$ where $V$ is a supplementary subspace. (in particular one can choose orthogonal basis, and the orthogonal subspace $N(I-K)^{\perp}$) $A$ is injective in restriction to $N(I-K)$ but $0$ on $V$. All in all, as a map from $H$ to itself it is not injective.

This proof is not easy, so I'll try to summarized it: suppose by absurd that $\mathrm{dim}\ N(I-K) < \mathrm{dim}\ R(I-K)^{\perp}$ then *there is* (not unique) a linear map $A:H \rightarrow R(I-K)^{\perp}$ which is injective in restriction to the subspace $ N(I-K)$, has kernel the orthogonal subspace $ N(I-K)^{\perp}$ (could be constructed so that the kernel is another supplementary subspace of $N(I-K)$), and $A$ is not surjective. Then one explicitly checks that $N(I- (K+A)) \subset \mathrm{Ker}(A) \cap N(I-K) = \{0\}$ and thus by (iv), $R(I- (K+A))= H$. This is impossible.

(You didn't ask why this was impossible but here is a way to see it: $u-Ku$ is by definition of "$R$", in $R(I-K)$ and $A u$ is in $R(A)$ which is a proper subspace of the orthogonal subspace $R(I-K)^{\perp}$ as $A$ is not surjective. Hence $u-Ku -A u \in R(I-K)\oplus R(A)$ which is a proper subspace of $R(I-K)\oplus R(I-K)^{\perp} = H$. "Proper subspace" means that there are vectors in $H$ which are not in the subspace.)

f.) The remark is based only on the statement of the theorem, not on the proof: ($\beta$) says in words $ N(I-K)\neq \{0\}$.

g.) Again, this statement has nothing to do with the proof or any assumption therein. It is a general dichotomy, it is the general case. $(\alpha)$ says $(I-K)$ is surjective and injective.